# eclipse not responding when code proposals dropdown opened

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I am using eclipse IDE for my project development , whenever code proposals drop-down opened my IDE stop responding and taking much time to recover back.

Below are my eclipse IDE details:

Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705

Whenever I press "." after a class or data structure this problem occuring (eclipse trying to display code proposals and its hanging) .

Please let me know what can be done to avoid this.

Comment: Eclipse Preferences > Java Editor > Content Assist > Disable Auto activation.

Comment: Abdullah , I think the above action will disable code assist , but I need assistance but it should not hang my IDE.

Comment: Go to Eclipse Preferences > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced and uncheck the proposals you do not need, that will make it a little faster

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for this, such as,

1) Due to low configuration of the system.

2) Due to running of many other programs, which is slowing down eclipse.

3) Due to usage of lot of API's or JAR's with multiple existence of same named class.

4) Older version of eclipse being used.

It had happened to me long ago.You can either disable or change the settings of content assist (Window/Preferences/Java/Editor/Content Assist/ Uncheck Auto Activation).

Try the same using Eclipse V 3.7.